# MongoDB: Element "sysinfo" not found

Tags: mongodb, mongovue

We successfully installed mongodb. However when we try to connect to it from Mongo Vue we are receiving following error. Any idea how to resolve this?

```
Connection was refused
Unable to connect to server Frontier:27017: Element 'sysInfo' not found..
Type: MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException
Stack:    at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.DirectMongoServerProxy.Connect(TimeSpan timeout, ReadPreference readPreference)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoServer.Connect(TimeSpan timeout)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoServer.Connect()
   at MangoUI.MMongo.QSDlL5xzK686iCExThO(Object )
   at MangoUI.MMongo.Open(Boolean mustWrite)
   at MangoUI.MMongo.Open()
   at MangoUI.MConnection.get_IsValid()
   at MangoUI.WinConnect.SCOjR9kYRPerNNngykW(Object )
   at MangoUI.WinConnect.btnTest_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)


Element 'sysInfo' not found.
Type: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException
Stack:    at MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument.get_Item(String name)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoServerBuildInfo.FromCommandResult(CommandResult result)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoServerInstance.LookupServerInformation(MongoConnection connection)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoServerInstance.Connect()
   at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.DirectMongoServerProxy.Connect(TimeSpan timeout, ReadPreference readPreference)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MongoDB 3.0, it will not work. I have not been able to get a response from the company.

I am thinking support for the product has stopped and the application is never going to be upgraded.